# Uniform convergeness and polynomials

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

If $f(x)$ is continuous function on $[a,b]\Rightarrow\exists <P_{n}(x)>$ sequence of polynomials such that $P_{n}(x)$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.
Is this statement true or false? Prove why?

This question came in an exam yesterday and I am ashamed to say that I didn't answer it because I didn't understand it. Could someone please explain this to me and whether its true or false.

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, so its true.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial